# Child component, infinitely re-rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having trouble understanding why my component is being infinitely re-rendered

Parent Render: this part is incredibly large so I'm only including the section that uses the child component

```
 <Container
              style={{ alignItems: "center", height: 350, width: 1000 }}
            >
                <RenderQuestion 
                    questionVersion={this.state.questionVersion}
                    base1={this.state.base1}
                    base2={this.state.base2}
                    exp1={this.state.exp1}
                    exp2={this.state.exp2}
                    ansbase={this.state.ansbase}
                    ansexp={this.state.ansexp}
                    multiple={this.state.multiple}
                    // EDIT: it might be a bit confusing but multiple here 
                    is just a randomly generated number
                />
   ...
</Container>
```

Child Component - RenderQuestion //this works normally

```
const RenderQuestion = (props) => {
    switch (props.questionVersion) {
    ...
    case 11:
            return(
                <Row style={{ paddingTop: "50px", fontFamily: "courier", fontWeight: "bold", fontSize: 70, }}>
                    {/* Left Side */}
                    <Col style={{
                        textAlign:"right"
                    }}>
                        <Undeterminable
                            operator={props.multiple}
                            base1={props.base1}
                            base2={props.base2}
                            exp1={props.exp1}
                            exp2={props.exp2}
                        />
                    </Col>

                    {/* Equal Sign */}
                    <Col xs="1">=</Col>
                    {/* Right Side */}
                    <Col xs="4" style={{
                        textAlign:"left"
                    }}>
                        <span>
                            {props.ansbase}<sup>{props.ansexp}</sup>
                        </span>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            );
     ...
```

Child's Child Component - Undeterminable //This is the part that is getting infinitely re-rendered

```
const Undeterminable = (props) => {
    let operator = "";
    let result = "";
    // random 1-4
    let random = Math.floor(Math.random()*4)+1;
    switch(props.operator) {
        case 1:
            operator = "+"
            break;
        case 2:
            operator = "-"
            break;
        case 3:
            operator = "x"
            break;
        case 4:
            operator = "÷"
            break;
    };

    switch(random){
        case 1:
            result = <span>
                ?<sup>{props.exp1}</sup>
                {" "} {operator} {" "}
                {props.base2}<sup>{props.exp2}</sup>
            </span>
            break;
        case 2:
            result = <span>
                {props.base1}<sup>?</sup>
                {" "} {operator} {" "}
                {props.base2}<sup>{props.exp2}</sup>
            </span>
            break;
        case 3:
            result = <span>
                {props.base1}<sup>{props.exp1}</sup>
                {" "} {operator} {" "}
                ?<sup>{props.exp2}</sup>
            </span>
            break;
        case 4:
            result = <span>
                {props.base1}<sup>{props.exp1}</sup>
                {" "} {operator} {" "}
                {props.base2}<sup>?</sup>
            </span>
            break;
    }
    return result;
}
```

To TL:DR depict what this code is supposed to do is it renders a basic equation with exponents
x^a (+/-/*/÷) y^b
where any of the numbers (x/a/y/b) are randomly loaded as a "?" instead of its value

However the component is being infinitely re-rendered so when displayed, it is constantly randomly changing which item is the "?", causing the equation to infinitely flicker and change. The wierdest thing about this is that the operator never changes during the infinite render.

EDIT: In Case 10 of my `RenderQuestion` I use a different child component `Multiple` which is this:

```
const Multiple = (props) => {
    let result = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < props.multiple -1; i++){
        result.push(<>{props.base1}<sup>{props.exp1}</sup> + </>)
    }
    
    return <span>{result}</span>;
};
```

which also infinitely renders (if i add console.log statements anywhere here, it will infinitely log), but since this doesn't change the displayed data or interfere with the rest of the app, I didnt mention it in the OP, but it seems more information might lead to a better understanding

Comment: Please include the code of the other component if it has a separate issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time your component is rendered, `random` is recalculated inside of `Undeterminable`. Notice that `operator` value is stored inside of `props`, and that has the correct behavior.

There are a couple of approaches you can take to fix your problem:

1. You can put `random` into your `props` to store the value.
2. Alternatively, you could store the value of `random` in the state, using something like the [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) hook.

For `useState`, make sure you import it and then try something like:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Undeterminable = (props) => {
  // random 1-4
  const [random] = useState(Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1);
  ...
}
```

Comment: I have a different `Child Child Component` that doesn't do any sort calculation, it has a simple for-loop and this component also infinitely renders. I didnt include it in the post because even though it is infinitely rendering, it doesn't change the displayed value, and the rest of my code functions properly regardless.

Comment: Thought of an answer that doesn't require you to change your props which uses `state` instead.